# How to create django model dependencies?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a django rest api for wiki application,
for now, I'm thinking of creation of 3 models:

1. `MainCategory` -> Linux or Windows
2. `SubCategory` for each operating system with a list of categories
3. `WikiContent` for each SubCategory

My problem that I don't know how to do in the right way because I want that for each category I will see only categories that depend on and not all the categories and WikiContent will see depends on which category the user chose.
Thanks for the help.

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Linux', 'Linux'),
        ('Windows', 'Windows')
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
        default='Linux',
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```py
class SubCategoryLinux(models.Model):
    
    # TYPE_CHOICES_LINUX = (
    #     ('Installs', 'Installs'),
    #     ('Sysaid', 'Sysaid'),
    #     ('DataBase', 'DataBase'),
    #     ('Docker', 'Docker'),
    #     ('Devops', 'Devops'),
    #     ('Linux Hardware', 'Linux Hardware'),
    #     ('Programming', 'Programming'),
    #     ('Monitoring', 'Monitoring')
    # )

    # TYPE_CHOICES_WIN = (
    #     ('Installs','Installs'),
    #     ('Sysaid', 'Sysaid')
    # )
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Content(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category')
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sub_category')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=40000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: It's really hard to read and understand. Please write more clearly with your models

Comment: @seuling Edited ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest you different design approach.

I dont know what your plans with Category/Subcategory are but as it is now, it contains only `name` - so i would argue that better approach would be to remove the Category/Subcategory table and adjust the Content model's category/subcategory to be only Charfield with choices as you have.

If you insist having separate tables for category and subcategory:

it depends what you plan to do it with the tables - if you only enter the categories/subcategories once and by yourself - I would recommend to simplify it and just simply remove the choices.

If you really need to have the choices based on the Main Linux/Windows choice, you will need to build the choices dynamically where you plan to use it ( as this is not clear at the moment ).